# How do I turn this into React Hooks for useEffect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to turn this into react hooks using `useEffect` but it keep giving me an error. The class name is not added or removed when I use `useEffect`.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;

        const img = document.getElementById("logo-img");
        const name = document.getElementById("name");

        if (isTop) {
            img.classList.remove("logo-small");
            name.classList.remove("no-display");
        } else {
            img.classList.add("logo-small");
            name.classList.add("no-display");
        }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll");
}
```

this is what I convert it into react hooks `useEffect`, when I implement this the class name is not remove or added

```js
useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;

        const img = document.getElementById("logo-img");
        const name = document.getElementById("name");

        if (isTop) {
            img.classList.remove("logo-small");
            name.classList.remove("no-display");
        } else {
            img.classList.add("logo-small");
            name.classList.add("no-display");
        }
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: What is the error you facing.

Comment: @abhay the classname is not remove or added

Comment: You can try useRef()

Comment: const img = imgRef.current img.classList.add('logo-small'); Somthing like that

Comment: Take a look to this link hope it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101660

Comment: Your code is working for me. Though if you want it to also apply classes before the scroll listener triggers you need to do so manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect), according to the documentation:

> **Tip**
>
> If you’re migrating code from a class component, note `useLayoutEffect` fires in the same phase as `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. However, we recommend starting with `useEffect` first and only trying `useLayoutEffect` if that causes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as is as far as I can tell. Working snippet below.

```js
const App = () => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    const // move queries outside of callback
      img = document.getElementById("logo-img"),
      name = document.getElementById("name"),
      handleLogoClasses = () => {
        const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;

        if (isTop) {
          img.classList.remove("logo-small");
          name.classList.remove("no-display");
        } else {
          img.classList.add("logo-small");
          name.classList.add("no-display");
        }
      }

    // call handleLogoClasses() or manually handle initial classes
    // handleLogoClasses()

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleLogoClasses);
    
    // return a callback for cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleLogoClasses);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='scroll'>
      <div id='logo-img'>
        logo-img
      </div>
      <div id='name' >
        name
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.scroll {
  height: 200vh;
}

#logo-img {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#name {
  position:fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

.logo-small {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.no-display {
  position:fixed;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I've moved the listener callback to a function, and moved the queries outside of it to avoid unnecessary DOM interaction on every firing of the event. I also added a `return` callback removing the listener for cleanup. If you want to apply classnames before the `scroll` listener fires just call the callback or add them manually.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);

  const // move queries outside of callback
    img = document.getElementById("logo-img"),
    name = document.getElementById("name"),
    handleLogoClasses = () => {
      const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;

      if (isTop) {
        img.classList.remove("logo-small");
        name.classList.remove("no-display");
      } else {
        img.classList.add("logo-small");
        name.classList.add("no-display");
      }
    }

  // call handleLogoClasses() or manually handle initial classes
  // handleLogoClasses()

  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleLogoClasses);

  // return a callback for cleanup
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleLogoClasses);
  }
}, []);
```

**useRef()**

Taking advantage of `useRef()` allows you to avoid querying the DOM directly instead letting React store the elements for you.

```js
const App = () => {
  const
    img = React.useRef(), name = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    const handleLogoClasses = () => {
      const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;
      // access the elements stored in ref.current
      if (isTop) {
        img.current.classList.remove("logo-small");
        name.current.classList.remove("no-display");
      } else {
        img.current.classList.add("logo-small");
        name.current.classList.add("no-display");
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleLogoClasses);

    // return a callback for cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleLogoClasses);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='scroll'>
      <div ref={img} id='logo-img'>
        logo-img (scroll to see change)
      </div>
      <div ref={name} id='name' >
        name
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.scroll {
  height: 200vh;
}

#logo-img {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#name {
  position:fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

.logo-small {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.no-display {
  position:fixed;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

```
const App = () => {
  const
    img = useRef(), name = useRef(); // <-- Declare refs

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ...
    
    const handleLogoClasses = () => {
      const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;

      if (isTop) {
        img.current.classList.remove("logo-small"); // <-- Access elements stored in ref
        name.current.classList.remove("no-display");
      } else {
       ...
      }
    }

    ...
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='scroll'>
      <div ref={img} id='logo-img'> {/* <-- Assign element to ref */}
      ...
  )
}
```

**useState()**

Even more React like would be to handle the styling using state. This allows you to keep all your `className` logic in the `jsx` rather than having to handle it manually in the listener callback, and the listener is just responsible for setting state appropriately. This requires making a separate `useEffect()` call for your initial `window.scroll()` which will only run once. And then declaring an `isTop` state and adding it to the dependency array of the `useEffect()` that handles the scroll listener. It is particularly important to handle cleanup as it will be recreating the listener every time the state changes.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isTop, setIsTop] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleIsTop = () => {
      const currentTop = window.scrollY < 50;
      if (currentTop !== isTop) {
        setIsTop(currentTop);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleIsTop);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleIsTop);
    }
  }, [isTop]);

  return (
    <div className='scroll'>
      <div id='logo-img' className={!isTop && 'logo-small'}>
        logo-img
      </div>
      <div id='name' className={!isTop && 'no-display'} >
        name
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.scroll {
  height: 200vh;
}

#logo-img {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#name {
  position:fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

.logo-small {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.no-display {
  position:fixed;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

```
const App = () => {
  const [isTop, setIsTop] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const
      handleIsTop = () => {
        const currentTop = window.scrollY < 100;

        if (currentTop !== isTop) {
          setIsTop(currentTop);
        }
      }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleIsTop);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleIsTop);
  }, [isTop]);

  return (
    <div className='scroll'>
      <div id='logo-img' className={!isTop && 'logo-small'}>
        logo-img
      </div>
      <div id='name' className={!isTop && 'no-display'} >
        name
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```